# Unable to find xpath using position(), last(),[1] indexing([1]--eg.) following:siblings, child, parent nothing is working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find out the XPATH. I am getting 30 matches for an element.

I tried using last(), position(), indexing[], child, parent, following:siblings, preceding:siblings, absolute XPATH is also not working, how to achieve this.

```
<div data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.3.1.0.0.0.0.0.2.0:$5.5.0"><span class="cursor" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.3.1.0.0.0.0.0.2.0:$5.5.0.0"><svg viewBox="0 0 16 20" class="excel-document" style="background-image:none;background-position:0% 0%;display:inline;fill:#333;height:20px;width:16px;" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.3.1.0.0.0.0.0.2.0:$5.5.0.0.0"><path d="M2 0C.9 0 .01.9.01 2L0 18c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2H14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6l-6-6H2zm7 7V1.5L14.5 7H9zm-2.34 7.39l-3.45-5.1h2.73l2.1 3.42 2.175-3.42h2.58L9.36 14.405 13.095 20H10.29l-2.34-3.705L5.565 20h-2.64l3.735-5.61z" fill="#11764B" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.3.1.0.0.0.0.0.2.0:$5.5.0.0.0.0"></path></svg></span>
```

Comment: Which _Selenium_ language bindings are you using? Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Its a react based applications

Comment: added html code

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed. Then we can tell you what you did wrong, and how to fix it. At the moment your questions says very little more than "I'm stuck, please help".

Comment: //span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document'][1]

Comment: //span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document']/following::sibling::*

Comment: And what's your expected output?

Comment: it should retrieve unique xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the first matching element of given xpath, then wrap the entire xpath with <kbd>()</kbd> and then provide the index as shown below.

First matching element:

```
 (//span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document'])[1]
```

Following Element to the first-matching Element:

```
(//span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document'])[1]/following-sibling::*
```

Last Element:

```
 (//span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document'])[last()]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!